# Android export wizards works, ANT does not, difference?

Tags: android, android-build

Android export wizards works, ant does not, difference?

MyProject
-> has AndroidProjectLibrary referenced
-> has AndroidProjectLibrary referenced (the option in eclipse that says add Project to the buidl path)

AndroidProjectLibrary (the option in eclipse that says add Project to the buidl path)
JavaLibrary

With eclpse: when using the export wizard of the ADT works fine.
But when using "ant debug" or "ant release" the classes of "JavaLibrary" are not found and the project can not be compiled. (I have the build.xml and the local and default properties set, run with android project update, etc)

If a copy the .class files from the bin folder from JavaLibrary to the bin folder from MyProject, then it can compile,o otherwise not.

My question is what the export wizard from android does differently than running "ant debug"?
And what is the solution for my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before using ant on an Android project you need to configure it.
use the following command from your project path (**SDK/plateform-tools** and **SDK/tools** must be on your `$PATH`):

```
android update project --path .
```

Then you will be able to do `ant help/clean/compile/debug/release`

Sometimes you will need to override default properties values from **SDK/tools/ant/main_rules.xml**, do that in a `build.properties` inside your project.